# How the string.charAt() works when passing in a string as argument?

Tags: javascript, string

According to [the MDN JS Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), the `charAt` method takes in an `integer` and returns an the character at the index. And

> If the index you supply is out of range, JavaScript returns an empty string.

What I found is that it also takes `string` as an argument and the return value is intriguing.

The example code: http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/4m3ZW/

```
var s = 'hey, have fun here.'
>>undefined
s.charAt(2);
>>"y" //works correct
s.charAt('2');
>>"y" //This works too
s.charAt('a');
>>"h" //This is intriguing
```

Does anyone have a clue how this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm is described in [Section 15.5.4.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.5.4.4) in the specification. There you will see (`pos` being the parameter passed to `charAt`):

> (...)
>   3. Let *position* be ToInteger(*pos*).
>   (...)

`ToInteger` is described in [Section 9.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.4):

> 1. Let *number* be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If *number* is **NaN**, return **+0**.
>      (...)

`'a'` is not a numerical string and hence cannot be converted to a number, so `ToNumber` will return `NaN` (see [Section 9.3.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.3.1)) which then results in `0`.

On the other side, if you pass a valid numerical string, such as `'2'`, `ToNumber` will convert it to the corresponding number, `2`.

---

Bottom line:

`s.charAt('a')` is the same as `s.charAt(0)`, because `'a'` cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: i see you updated your answer and the up votes come flying in